# Android Media player character by character

Tags: android

I am working with media player. I want to play the sound of each character displayed on textview in android.

I am using this to display character one by one, as character displayed, want to play the corresponding sound.

```
public void delayedPrint(int delay, String s) {
    try {
        for (char c : s.toCharArray()) {
            System.out.println(c);
            Thread.sleep(delay);
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    }

    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: How do determine what sound to play for a given character?

Comment: You have to use `TextToSpeech` idea instead of media player. using that you can solve your problem.

Comment: I have sounds for each character in apps raw folder, that i want to play, like if text contains "apple" need to play alphabet sound as a p p l e one by one.